# How do I Start Dell EMC PowerEdge XR2 Server automatically when a power source is connected?

Tags: dell-poweredge

Is there a way to boot on a Dell PowerEdge XR2 server once power is connected to it, similar to how an [Intel NUC can boot on power](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000054773/intel-nuc/intel-nuc-mini-pcs.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Required notice: I work for Dell)

What you likely want is AC power recovery.

[image]

> Specifies how the system reacts after AC power has been restored to
> the system. It is especially useful when systems are turned off with a
> power strip. When set to Off, the system stays off after AC power is
> restored. When set to On, the system turns on after AC power is
> restored. When set to Last, the system turns on if the system was on
> at the moment when AC power was lost. The system will remain off if
> the system was turned off when AC power was lost. In case of an
> ungraceful shutdown, the system always turns on. Note:The host will
> not power up until iDRAC Root of Trust (RoT) is completed, host power
> on will be delayed by minimum 90 seconds after the A/C applied.

On the iDRAC it is under Configuration -> BIOS Settings -> System Security -> AC Power Recovery

In your case, you would want it set to On instead of the default of Last.

Comment: Thanks! Additionally, if iDRAC is unavailable for some reason, you can boot into the BIOS using a VGA and keyboard and mouse and go to System BIOS -> System Security -> AC Power Recovery.